# PostgreSQL via SSH Tunnel

Tags: postgresql, ssh, tunnel, razorsql

I'd like to use RazorSQL to connect to my database which is running on a remote server. I create a SSH tunnel on my localhost with the following command:

```
ssh -L 1111:remote.server.com:5432 myuser@remote.server.com
```

I configure my connection via RazorSQL's GUI, specifying `localhost` as the host and `1111` as the port. When I click on "Connect", the following error message appears:

```
ERROR: An error occurred while trying to make a connection to
the database: 

JDBC URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:1111/myuser

FATAL:
no pg_hba.conf entry for host "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd",
user "myuser", database "mydatabase", SSL off
```

where `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` is a remote server's IP address.

What is more, I am not allowed to change the contents of my `pg_hba.conf` file. That's how it look like at the moment:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

@remove-line-for-nolocal@# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
@remove-line-for-nolocal@local   all         all                               @authmethod@
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          @authmethod@
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               @authmethod@
```

Is it possible to connect to the database server via SSH tunnel using my current setup and without modifying the server's configuration?

Comment: What is `@authmethod@` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Your pg_hba.conf appears to permit connections from localhost. The easiest way of causing your SSH tunnel connections to appear from localhost is to make them **to** localhost.

The following SSH command connects to remote.example.com as user "user", and causes your ssh client to listen on localhost, port 1111/tcp. Any connections made to that port will be forwarded over the ssh tunnel, and on the ssh server side the connections will be made to localhost, port 5432/tcp. Since we're connecting to localhost, the connections will appear to be from localhost also, and should match your existing pg_hba.conf line.

```
ssh -L 1111:localhost:5432 user@remote.example.com
```

If this is expected to be a long-running tunnel, I would recommend using [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/)

To connect using the psql client on the host where you are running the ssh client, use something like this:

```
psql -h localhost -p 1111 -U your-db-username database-name
```

You should then be prompted for your database user's password.

Alternately, you can add a line line the following to a file called `.pgpass` in your home directory on the client where you're running psql:

```
localhost:1111:database-name:your-db-user:your-db-password
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an error: ` FATAL:
password authentication failed for user "myuser" `

Comment: If you are receiving a `FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myuser"`, confirm that your username and password are valid credentials for the remote PostgreSQL instance. I've updated the answer with an example of how to connect through the tunnel using the psql client.

Comment: Nope, that's not the cause. I used ssh, autossh, I change psql client, tried it on windows, linux... Everywhere I get the aforementioned error. In the next few days I'm going to contact with the server's admin. I hope he find possible reason/solution to my problem.

Comment: `ALTER USER my-db-user WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'my-db-password'` solves the problem definietely. @jeff, thanks for replies!

Comment: kozoh did you find a way to make this the default setting? Kinda be lame to be expected to do this in ever database I create.

Comment: @PhilDonovan, nope, I didn't need it, sorry. But I think you can write a simple script that will automize your creation of a database.

Comment: @kozooh Yes! Thank-you, thank-you!! Been messing with this for 3 days. If I ssh into machine, I can login to psql console using password. BUT, if I try to connect through an ssh tunnel, it would always give me an "password authentication failed..." error. WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a Demo:**

Open two cmd windows

Enter password when prompting

#### First

ssh -N -L 1111:127.0.0.1:5432 oracle@10.16.15.13
[image]

#### Second

cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin

psql -h localhost -p 1111 -U postgres postgres
[image]

Check Date and version
[image]

Thanks!