# Postgres connect over ssh

Tags: postgresql, ssh

I have PostgreSQL server running on some host `pgserver`. This server is not opened to the outside world (only connections from `localhost` are allowed). I can login to that host as `user` via ssh (with public key):

```
me@local:~ $ ssh user@pgserver
```

Then I can `su` to specific user `pguser` to run queries.

```
user@pgserver:~ $ sudo su pguser
pguser@pgserver:~ $ psql
```

I need to enter `user`'s sudo-password here. I can't connect as `pguser` and don't know his password. I also don't have access to the database as `user`.

Now to simplify development I would like to setup ssh-tunnel from my local machine to the `pgserver`:

```
me@local:~ $ ssh -L localhost:5432:localhost:5432 user@pgserver
```

The problem is that while `user` has access to the server, he doesn't have access to database. `pguser` has it, but doesn't have access to the server. What is frustrating is that I can actually `sudo` to `pguser`'s account and run queries after I've connected as `user`.

Can I solve this in some way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL via SSH Tunnel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835761/postgresql-via-ssh-tunnel)

Comment: @e4c5 In my case I don't know `pguser`'s password

Answer (score 2):

Try

`ssh -t -l user pgserver sudo -u pguser psql`

The -t forces ssh to allocate a pty on the other end so there's
a terminal for password input and such.