# Postgresql Java jdbc connect via SSL tunnel to a DB running in Virtualbox using .pem file

Tags: java, postgresql, ssl, jdbc, dbeaver

Hi I am trying to connect to a local Postgres Db running in Virtualbox Centos, which connects through SSL tunnel. Example of how I connect via DBeaver is below.

1. DBeaver I am using a SSL tunnel tab and
2. I am using a pem file, and user and password

Postgres local connection[image]

3. The Virtualbox is set to forward port as follows

Postgres Virtualbox port forward[image]

My Java code without ssl tunnel is this

`DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbName?user=postgresuser&password=givepassword");`

This is failing saying `pg_hba.conf` not found etc or if I give `ssl=true` in connection string , says its not supported.. How do I connect to Local DB using ssl tunnel?
[ My assumption in that pg_hba.conf file would be available on the Virtualbox Host Vm only.]

Comment: can you post the java code?

Comment: I dont have any other except above: this one connects :: 
`DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbName?user=postgresuser&password=givepassword");`

Comment: does this work -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835761/postgresql-via-ssh-tunnel

Comment: It already works, I am able to connect. The issues is not if i can connect or not. I want code example in Java how to do same.

Comment: @NxFi did you manage to get a working example to replicate what DBeaver was doing to establish the ssh tunnel? can you share your solution

Answer (score 0):

You may try using [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) which is an implementation of SSH in Java.

Here is a complete example of how to do it https://cryptofreek.org/2012/06/06/howto-jdbc-over-an-ssh-tunnel/

Note that in this case all your traffic will go to the proxy hence you need to close the session after reading/writting to the database.