# Connecting with RDS Postgresql db works from PgAdmin 4 tool, but when i try the same using C# application, it fails to connect

Tags: c#, postgresql, amazon-rds, pgadmin-4

Connecting with RDS Postgresql db works from PgAdmin 4 tool, but when i try the same using C# application, it fails with the error `"28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.195.91.228", user "postgres", database "mydatabase", no encryption"`

I am using SSH tunnelling for this.

Sample code:

```cs
string connString = "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=***;Database=sampleDb";
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
```

Is there anyway we can pass pg_hba.conf details in C# ?

Connecting with RDS Postgresql db works from PgAdmin 4 tool, but when i try the same using C# application, it fails with the error `"28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.195.91.228", user "postgres", database "mydatabase", no encryption"`

Expected results:
Connection should be successful

Comment: Since the server IP is revealed (instead of localhost), you will likely have to change how you establish the tunnel. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835761/postgresql-via-ssh-tunnel).

Comment: It looks like you are connecting without SSL, while the server demands use of SSL.  Either configure your server not to demand SSL (it is of questionable utility when already going through a tunnel) or configure Npgsql to use SSL.  https://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html

Comment: @JGH  When using a tunnel, the 'localhost' in the connection string just directs you to the local end of the tunnel.  Where the DB server sees the connection coming from will likely be different.